# How to know if the left button of mouse pressed - Assembly

Tags: assembly, mouse

i wanna do a game that while i pressed on a character it changes place.

Is there a int or something to check if the left button pressed (in that time),
and then i will check if that on the character.

Thank you!!

Comment: Which OS? What architecture?

Comment: OP's previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48815410/using-the-mouse-in-a-game, so this is probably x86-16 with DOS `int 21h` interrupts.